# cleaning trombone slide where outer slide is under the inner slide

Tags: maintenance, trombone, instrument-cleaning

I have been playing for some time, but have never found a good way to clean the inner slide up inside the part where the outer slide is under the metal in first position

[image: http://imgur.com/MSNOZLN)]

I've tried tooth picks and cloths and water and detergent, but it can't be cleaned with a cloth like the rest of the inner slide because the space is just big enough for the thickness of the outer slide.

This is the only place where my slide gums up, any ideas/pro tips?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you take the slide completely out and clean it?
and use a pipe-cleaner style piece to clean inside the slides?

Answer (score 0):

Brew it yourself stores sell small brushes which are used to clean beer and wine bottles .

Also , science and chemistry stores sell small brushes for cleaning test tubes .

Malcolm